# IBM integration Bus v10 with latest EGit

Tags: egit, ibm-integration-bus

When you try to install latest EGit with IBM Integration Toolkit with "Help -> Marketplace -> Search EGit", the following error is thrown:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Git integration for Eclipse 5.8.1.202007141445-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 5.8.1.202007141445-r)
Missing requirement: Git integration for Eclipse 5.8.1.202007141445-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 5.8.1.202007141445-r) requires 'org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.12.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be found
```

Any possible remedy, other than downloading an older version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a hack to achieve this from within IBM integration toolkit.
If we instead install "Eclipse Web Developer Tools" it works.

During install, it asks you if you want to deploy EGit and usually important tools. Check all boxes and install them. This worked for IBM Integration toolkit 10.0.0.15.

Answer (score 2):

The IBM Integration Toolkit is based on Eclipse 4.4 (Luna), see "Help -> About IBM Integration Toolkit".

The table [What version of Eclipse does EGit target](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ#What_versions_of_Eclipse_does_EGit_target.3F) documents that for Luna the latest supported EGit version is 5.0.3. The table [Where can I find older releases of EGit](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ#Where_can_I_find_older_releases_of_EGit.3F) tells you to use the https://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-5.0.3 p2 repository URL.

Answer (score -1):

I have installed it on WMB and IIB toolkits, I used the versions mentioned

http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-2.1

Steps or what to select available in this link
https://ibmintegration.wordpress.com/2020/09/12/installing-e-git-on-iib-wmb/